# Cech cohomology on product covers & Fréchet sheaves

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sheaf-theory, tensor-products, sheaf-cohomology, topological-vector-spaces

My question is about the paper [Ka67].

Let $S, T$ be sheaves of nuclear Fréchet spaces over paracompact topological spaces $X, Y$, respectively; in particular, if $V \subset U$ are open subsets in $X$, the restriction maps $S(U) \to S(V)$ are all continuous, and analogously for $T$. Denote also by $\mathbin{\hat \otimes}$ the completed projective tensor product of two vector spaces.

Kaup defines a product sheaf $S \mathbin{\hat \otimes} T$ as follows: assign to an open set of the form $U \times V \subset X \times Y$ the set $S(U) \mathbin{\hat \otimes} T(V)$, with restrictions maps
$$S(U_1) \mathbin{\hat \otimes} T(V_1) \to S(U_2) \mathbin{\hat \otimes} T(V_2)$$
defined as the tensor product of the restriction maps of $S$ and $T$. This defines a presheaf on a topological base, and Kaup argues that this extends to a sheaf on all of $X \times Y$ (even a sheaf of Fréchet spaces, but details on this are omitted).

Now, given two open covers $\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V}$ of $X$ and $Y$, one can define a product cover $\mathcal{W}_{\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V}} := \{U \times V : U \in \mathcal{U}, V \in \mathcal{V}\}$.

**Question:** Consider Cech cohomology with respect to these covers. Do we have (as topological vector spaces or abelian groups)
$$ \check{H}^\bullet (X \times Y, S  \mathbin{\hat \otimes} T) \cong \varinjlim_{\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V}} \check{H}^\bullet(\mathcal{W}_{\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V}}, S  \mathbin{\hat \otimes} T)?$$
In other words, can Cech cohomology, as an inductive limit over all open covers of $X \times Y$, be calculated by restricting to product covers $\mathcal{W}_{\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V}}$ only?
What about when $S$ and $T$ admit Leray coverings?

---

A few remarks: This would be trivial if the set of product covers $\mathcal{W}_{\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V}}$ were cofinal in the set of all open covers of $X \times Y$, but this is not the case: For example, on $(0,1)^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, imagine a cover by open rectangles so that the width of a rectangle which contains $(x,y) \in (0,1)$ is at most $y$. This cannot be refined by any product cover $\mathcal{W}_{\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V}}$, since if an open set in $\mathcal{U}$ contains an interval of width $c$, then there are open sets in $\mathcal{W}_{\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V}}$ containing rectangles of width $c$, some of which will contain points $(x,y)$ with $y < c$.

I believe this would also be true if $\mathbin{\hat \otimes}$ were replaced by an algebraic tensor product, since then I believe one can show that a product cover of a Leray cover is a Leray cover of the product sheaf, using the Godement resolution and the usual Künneth formula for the algebraic tensor product of sheaves.

This statement seems to be what Kaup is implicitly using in the paper, towards his goal of proving a Künneth formula, see the sentence right before Theorem I in [Ka67]. In a later paper [Ka68, Satz 2] he says this follows when both $S$ and $T$ admit Leray covers, and he seems to imply that the product cover $\mathcal{W}_{U,V}$ is a Leray cover when $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ are, but I do not think this is outright stated anywhere. There are also assumptions about Hausdorffness of the spaces $\check{H}^\bullet(\mathcal{U},S)$ and $\check{H}^\bullet(\mathcal{V},T)$, but I think these are mainly to fix the topology of the direct limit.

[Ka67] *Kaup, Ludger*, [**Eine Künnethformel für Frechetgarben**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01111357), Math. Z. 97, 158-168 (1967). [ZBL0191.53701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0191.53701).

[Ka68] *Kaup, Ludger*, [**Ein Satz über topologische Urbildgarben**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01898775), Arch. Math. 19, 516-524 (1968). [ZBL0181.26303](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0181.26303).